# JSON object showing objects in console but also contains 'undefined' from string returned by php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a php script that queries my database for some values and puts them into a json string.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['name']) === true && empty($_POST['name']) === false) {
    include_once("../php_scripts/connect.php");

    $arr = array();
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT due_date FROM payment_due_dates WHERE client_id = '" . $_POST['name']. "'")) {
        $rowCount = $result->num_rows;

        echo '[';
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($i <= $rowCount - 2){
                echo json_encode($row);
                echo ',';
            }else{
                echo json_encode($row);
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $result->free();
    }
    echo ']';   
}

?>
```

Then jquery converts into a json object and adds the values to a select box.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $('#subName').click(function(){

                var name = $('input#txtName').val();

                if($.trim(name) != ''){
                    $.post('ajax/load_patient_episodes.php', {name: name}, function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                    console.log(obj);
                        var output;
                        $.each(obj, function(key, val){
                            output += '<option>' + val.due_date + '</option>';
                        });
                        $('#selEpisode2').html("<option>" + output + "</option>");
                    });
                }
          });
        });
```

It loads the values but also gives this error in my console log:

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault()
instead. jquery.js:5
```

and, when it adds the values to the selectbox it also adds the text 'undefined'. So the options in my select box appear as:

undefined

2013-11-13

2013-11-13

2013-11-13

I'm assuming it may have something to do with the *proto* array that is in there but I'm not sure how it got there. Still somewhat a newbie on this stuff. Here is my console log. Any ideas how I can lose the 'undefined in my select options?' Also, is there a better way I should be going about loading select options from a php query?

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault()
instead. jquery.js:5
[Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: *DO NOT* manually create your own JSON string!  Create an array, then use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).

Comment: Would I create the JSON array in php, echo it back, then parse? Sorry still new to ajax.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it works.  P.S. You can just do `$.post(url, {your: data}, function(d){}, 'json');`  The `,'json'` tells jQuery to parse the JSON for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var output = '';
$.each(obj, function(key, val){
  if (typeof (val.due_date) != undefined) { 
    output += '<option>' + val.due_date + '</option>';
  }
});
```

You might also want to SELECT UNIQUE due_date.

Comment: Just initializing the var output fixed it. Thanks! Sometimes it's just the little things.

Answer (score 0):

Hope, your `jquery` version is old, so can you download  the latest jquery version and include into you files,

Download: http://jquery.com/download/

Or, you can include the below one,

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize variable output with blank value

```
var output= "";
```